# how to implement printf for arm64 bare-metal?

Tags: gcc, arm, arm64

I'm trying to make print usable for an arm64 platform (bare-metal, compiler is aarch64-none-elf-gcc).
If I naively compile a simple hello_world.c program containing printf, I get errors as I expected. The errors are like below.

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/prj/abdsn/ab21u/ab21zeus/simoob$ arm-none-elf-gcc tt.c
....aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/stdlib/exit.c:64: undefined reference to `_exit'
....aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:51: undefined reference to `_sbrk'
....aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/writer.c:49: undefined reference to `_write'
....aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/closer.c:47: undefined reference to `_close'
....aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/lseekr.c:49: undefined reference to `_lseek'
....aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/readr.c:49: undefined reference to `_read'
....aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/fstatr.c:55: undefined reference to `_fstat'
....aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/isattyr.c:52: undefined reference to `_isatty'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The toolchain is looking for _exit, _sbrk, _write, _close, _lseek, _lread, _fstat, _isatty which I should  probably supply for the linker to link. But I guess because arm64 is being widely used, there should be some codes I can just reference/download and fix a little for our UART IP and use. Can anyone give me some direction?
In the past, someone in our team seem to have borrowed linux code and separate printf which uses our uart IP (using sparc architecture). I'm not sure if I should do the similar thing for this case too.

Comment: If you are using UART, add these compile options `-D USE_SERIAL_PORT -D STANDALONE`. Otherwise add this linker option `--specs=rdimon.specs`

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE I've tried that but it's the same.  I haven't provided how printf is connected to my uart yet. I don't know in what code I have to insert it.

Comment: I haven't read the answer yet but this seems likely to give me some good info. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014043/how-do-you-implement-printf-in-gcc-from-newlib

Comment: by definition bare metal means no operating system.  the C library has a heavy reliance on a "system" to handle system calls.  So first you need to seriously think about if you really need this, printf is often not needed, and it is massive with the amount of code it sucks in.  but quite doable using something like newlib and filling in all of those system level functions you called out.  for a simple print out a uart, it is easy to implement/fake those for the stdout handle.

Comment: start by rolling your own print util, print a number out in hex, you can fake the system utils to just pass and get it to build then watch what gets called in what order with what arguments, and then go from there.  I used to do this but long long ago realized I had no real use for C libraries in bare metal, wasnt worth it...

Comment: You are not the first one to have crossed this bridge in general or for arm64, you are not blazing new territory, so the other option is to just use something that exists...it may closer resemble an operating system than bare metal, but that is basically what you are after.