# STM32 C++ and Retargeting std::cout to UART

Tags: c++, arm, stm32, iostream, cout

I'm having trouble trying to get std::cout working on an STM32 using the STM32CubeIDE (generally a standard install of the STM32CubeIDE out of the package).

I've reviewed many sources about redirecting UART for the purposes of stdio.h and printf, but am trying to get this all working in a C++ environment using std::cout.  The prime source I've found is here:  https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlib/armlib_chr1358938931411.htm

I'm getting different errors depending on how and when I include headers, here is what I have tried:

retarget.h:

```
#ifndef _RETARGET_H__
#define _RETARGET_H__

#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void RetargetInit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);

int _isatty(int fd);
int _write(int fd, char* ptr, int len);
int _close(int fd);
int _lseek(int fd, int ptr, int dir);
int _read(int fd, char* ptr, int len);
int _fstat(int fd, struct stat* st);


namespace std {

int fputc(int, FILE *);

}

#endif //#ifndef _RETARGET_H__
```

retarget.cc (snipped a bit) [Corrected that this is a c++ file]

```
void RetargetInit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
  gHuart = huart;

  /* Disable I/O buffering for STDOUT stream, so that
   * chars are sent out as soon as they are printed. */
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
}

int _write(int fd, char* ptr, int len) {
  HAL_StatusTypeDef hstatus;

  if (fd == STDOUT_FILENO || fd == STDERR_FILENO) {
    hstatus = HAL_UART_Transmit(gHuart, (uint8_t *) ptr, len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    if (hstatus == HAL_OK)
      return len;
    else
      return EIO;
  }
  errno = EBADF;
  return -1;
}

namespace std {

struct __FILE
{
  int handle;
  /* Whatever you require here. If the only file you are using is */
  /* standard output using printf() for debugging, no file handling */
  /* is required. */
};
FILE __stdout;
FILE __stdin;
FILE __stderr;


int fputc(int c, FILE *stream)
{
      char tOut = c;

      return _write(STDOUT_FILENO, &tOut, 1);

  /* Your implementation of fputc(). */
}

}
```

and main.cpp (snipped a bit as well):

```
#include "retarget.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  /* HAL Init stuff Clipped */
  RetargetInit(&huart1);
  std::cout << "\n\nSTM32 main.c Startup\n" << std::endl;

  while(1){
      std::cout << "*";

      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

If I go printf (change  to  and the std::cout to printf), everything works fine, so the _write function works correctly for sending to UART, so I know that much is working.

Now, on to the errors.

As presented, the complier throws:

```
In file included from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\ext\string_conversions.h:43,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\bits\basic_string.h:6557,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\string:55,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\ios:42,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\ostream:38,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\iostream:39,
                 from ../Core/Src/main.cc:26:
c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\cstdio:111:11: error: 'int fputc(int, FILE*)' conflicts with a previous declaration
  111 |   using ::fputc;
      |           ^~~~~
In file included from ../Core/Src/main.cc:25:
../Core/Inc/retarget.h:23:5: note: previous declaration 'int std::fputc(int, FILE*)'
   23 | int fputc(int, FILE *);
      |     ^~~~~
make: *** [Core/Src/subdir.mk:41: Core/Src/main.o] Error 1
```

If I flip the includes in my main.cc file so that iostream is pulled in first, I get:

```
In file included from ../Core/Src/main.cc:26:
../Core/Inc/retarget.h:23:22: error: 'int std::fputc(int, FILE*)' conflicts with a previous declaration
   23 | int fputc(int, FILE *);
      |                      ^
In file included from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\cstdio:42,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\ext\string_conversions.h:43,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\bits\basic_string.h:6557,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\string:55,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\ios:42,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\ostream:38,
                 from c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\c++\10.3.1\iostream:39,
                 from ../Core/Src/main.cc:25:
c:{stm32 tools path snipped}arm-none-eabi\include\stdio.h:214:5: note: previous declaration 'int fputc(int, FILE*)'
  214 | int fputc (int, FILE *);
      |     ^~~~~
make: *** [Core/Src/subdir.mk:41: Core/Src/main.o] Error 1
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `namespace std {` why are you doing anything with namespace std in a C source file? `an STM32 using the STM32CubeIDE` this is your IDE, it is not relevant. What __compiler__ are you using? `The prime source` Yes, for Keil ARM C/C++ compiler. Are you using it? I would suspect you are using GCC and newlib, in which case https://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean9/ean9-howto-newlib-1.0.html#id2719973

Comment: Sorry for the typos in the file names.  These are C++ source files (retarget.cc and main.cc), and they are being compiled with g++.

I'll have to look into newlib, I don't recognize that from anything I've seen yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you Implement printf in GCC from Newlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014043/how-do-you-implement-printf-in-gcc-from-newlib)

Comment: Looking at the linked newlib porting guide, I already have _write implemented (which makes printf work).  I tried copying that to just write (no underbar) and it made no difference.   One thing that I have noticed, is that printf also does not work when compiled with g++ (in c++ files), but works fine when compiled with gcc (using c files).

Comment: That second link you posted does not help, either.  I am specifically trying to get std::cout working.  I have printf() working fine (when working with C files and gcc), but nothing works (neither printf or std::cout) when I compile with g++ ( when working with c++ files).

Comment: std::cout uses printf (fwrite). Research std::sync_with_stdio. Research stream buffering. You did not flush the stream on `std::cout << "*";`, so it is is buffered...

Comment: You caught the only line I don't flush! :)   All of my other lines use std::endl (which flushes).

Comment: No changes when std::ios::sync_with_stdio(true); or std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false); is added in main() before any (properly flushed) I/O operations.

Comment: Could you post the actual code that you are using with newlib? And remove the code related to keil?

Comment: https://github.com/cnoviello/mastering-stm32/blob/master/nucleo-f030R8/system/src/retarget/retarget.c

This is what I am using that works for printf() when compiling with gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally stumbled across the solution, and it came down to how the `_write()` function was compiled.  This function *must* be compiled with a C compiler to work correctly (as far as I can tell).

So, **the solution**, as far as is working for me:

I renamed `retarget.cc` back to `retarget.c` (it remains [`retarget.c`](https://github.com/cnoviello/mastering-stm32/blob/master/nucleo-f030R8/system/src/retarget/retarget.c), unmodified except for the include path for `retarget.h`).

For `retarget.h` I used the associated file for [`retarget.h`](https://github.com/cnoviello/mastering-stm32/blob/master/nucleo-f030R8/system/include/retarget/retarget.h) wrapped the function prototypes in extern "C":"

```
#ifndef _RETARGET_H__
#define _RETARGET_H__

#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void RetargetInit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);

int _isatty(int fd);
int _write(int fd, char* ptr, int len);
int _close(int fd);
int _lseek(int fd, int ptr, int dir);
int _read(int fd, char* ptr, int len);
int _fstat(int fd, struct stat* st);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} //extern "C"
#endif

#endif //#ifndef _RETARGET_H__
```

Now everything is working as expected - `std::cout << "Working now!" << std::endl;`

Comment: You don't actually need to rename the files. Using the `extern "C"` construct in the `.cc` files is enough. Also, there is no need to redeclare the `_write`, `_close`, etc. These are weakly defined in `syscalls.c`, which means they will already be getting used in one of the `unistd.h` declarations. Just include the latter in your file and redefine the functions in a `C` construct (file or extern) and you're good to go.